# Extract text after specific character

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to extract the word after the `@`

How can I do that? What I am trying:

```
text="Hello there @bob !"
user=text[text.find("@")+1:]
print user
```

output:

```
bob !
```

But the correct output should be:

```
bob
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A regex solution for fun:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'@(\w+)', '@Hello there @bob @!')
['Hello', 'bob']
>>> re.findall(r'@(\w+)', 'Hello there bob !')
[]
>>> (re.findall(r'@(\w+)', 'Hello there @bob !') or None,)[0]
'bob'
>>> print (re.findall(r'@(\w+)', 'Hello there bob !') or None,)[0]
None
```

The regex above will pick up patterns of one or more alphanumeric characters following an '@' character until a non-alphanumeric character is found.

Here's a regex solution to match one or more non-whitespace characters if you want to capture a broader range of substrings:

```
>>> re.findall(r'@(\S+?)', '@Hello there @bob @!')
['Hello', 'bob', '!']
```

Note that when the above regex encounters a string like `@xyz@abc` it will capture `xyz@abc` in one result instead of `xyz` and `abc` separately. To fix that, you can use the negated `\s` character class while also negating `@` characters:

```
>>> re.findall(r'@([^\s@]+)', '@xyz@abc some other stuff')
['xyz', 'abc']
```

And here's a regex solution to match one or more alphabet characters only in case you don't want any numbers or anything else:

```
>>> re.findall(r'@([A-Za-z]+)', '@Hello there @bobv2.0 @!')
['Hello', 'bobv']
```

Comment: I was just about to post this, as splitting on '@' could get convoluted for multiple names (like the @there example) - so this is one of those times I recommend a regex....man, beating me to the punch :P ;)

Answer (score 9):

So you want the word starting after @ up to a whitespace?

```
user=text[text.find("@")+1:].split()[0]
print(user)
bob
```

EDIT: as @bgstech note, in cases where the string does not have a "@", make a check before:

```
if "@" in text:
    user=text[text.find("@")+1:].split()[0]
else:
    user="something_else_appropriate"
```

Comment: This is good, but what happens if there's no '@' symbol in the original string?

Comment: Well, in that case user will be the first substring before whitespace. I'm not sure if that's a possibility in the OPs case, but I'll add a note in the post.

Comment: Yeah @OdiogoSilva, agreed it's not perhaps possible in the OP's case, but I think your edit makes for a nice complete answer -- upvoting!

Comment: Or you could just use `split` instead of `find` in the first place. For example (depending on what the OP wants), `text.split("@", 1)[-1].split()[0]` is simpler, and easier to understand if you want to change it to something different (like always take the last "@" instead of the first, or treat no "@" as an error instead, etc.).