# Python - Capture next word after specific string in a text

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to only capture 1 word after a specific string. For example,

```
import re
my_string="I love Apple juice, it is delicious."
print(my_string.split("I love",1)[-1])
```

I get result:

```
Apple juice, it is delicious.
```

But I just need 1 word, nothing after that.

```
Apple
```

How to do I remove every thing after Apple? I tried `rstrip`, it works but not the best efficient way. Thanks.

Comment: `print(my_string.split("I love",1)[-1].split()[0])`

Comment: `my_string.split("I love ", 1)[1].split()[0]`.

Comment: Why not just keep doing what you're already doing and go with `my_string.split('I love', 1)[-1].strip().split(' ')[0]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract text after specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836812/extract-text-after-specific-character)

Comment: Why `import re` if you're using `str.split()`? OR why not `re.search('I love (\w+)', s).groups()[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `str.split` twice and make sure you use `maxsplit` to avoid unwanted splitting:

```
my_string = 'I love Apple juice, it is delicious.'

res = my_string.split('I love', maxsplit=1)[-1]\
               .split(maxsplit=1)[0]

'Apple'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd try a positive lookbehind in your regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string="I love Apple juice, it is delicious."
>>> re.search('(?<=I love )(\w+)', my_string).group(1)
'Apple'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the positive look ahead Regex group construct:

```
match = re.search('(?<=I love\s)\S*', 'I love Apple juice, it is delicious.')
```

edit: I miss read your question and updated my pattern to match what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't match "Apple" as asked for in the post.

Comment: I miss read what you were try to match. I have updated my pattern accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. In the simplest form you can do:

```
>>> s = 'Apple juice, it is delicious.'
>>> s.split()[0]
'Apple'
```

Or use the fully-featured regular expression (`import re`)

```
>>> re.search(r'^[\S]*(?!\S\s)', s)
'Apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
my_string="I love Apple juice, it is delicious."
print( re.findall(r"\bI\s+love\s+(\w+)", my_string) )
# => ['Apple']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BV4h4b) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iq2l1X/1). **Note** that [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) returns all found matches in the string, and since there is a single capturing group in the pattern the returned strings will be the Group 1 values.

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `I` - an `I` word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces (what if the space is a non-breaking space? `\s` handles these cases well)
- `love` - a `love` word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more letters, digits or underscores.